# Есть ли в предложении ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Порой слова бывают дороже чем сам человек, А порою слово сказанное самим человеком, снижает его же ценность.

Всё ли здесь правильно?

Comment: Неясно: ценность _кого_ или _чего_ (слова или человека) вы имели в виду?

Comment: Снижает ценность человека

Comment: Тогда лучше сказать " ценность его самого", так однозначнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Увы, не всё здесь правильно.

Правильно будет так (если это всё-таки одно предложение, как спрошено в шапке вопроса, и запятая перед прописной ***А*** - просто опечатка):

*Порой слова бывают дороже, чем сам человек, а порою слово, сказанное самим человеком, снижает его же ценность.*

Добавленные запятые:

первая - перед сравнительным оборотом,

вторая открывает причастный оборот.